# My virtual environment doesn't work in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I just changed my work computer and installed python with anaconda. I've also installed VScode. I created an environment named 'myprojects' in conda. I used 'activate' to run the code I wrote in vscode with this environment, but it didn't work. what should I do?

[here's what looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm0IO.png)

I just wrote some code and then I wanted to run the code in the environment I created before. Normally the line below should start with (myprojects). but it didn't work. why did this happen? what should I do?

Comment: A virtual environment would require `source envname/bin/activate`. For a Conda environment, you'd use `conda activate envname`.  `activate` just by itself is likely not good enough.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the virtual environment directory by below command:

```
cd myprojects
cd Scripts
```

then simply run a file 'activate'

```
activate
```